# htaccess redirect one file to another including query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How would one redirect an image url to a php script while preserving the full query string using htaccess and mod_rewrite

so for example:

```
image.jpg?a=1&b=2&c=4
```

should redirect transparently to:

```
image.php?a=1&b=2&c=4
```

where the query string can contain some or all of these parameters or others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> redirect transparently

So, you mean an *internal rewrite*, not strictly a "redirect" (which implies an *external* 3xx HTTP "redirect").

I assume `image.jpg` and `image.php` are in the document root.

You would do something like this using mod_rewrite in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(image)\.jpg$ $1.php [L]
```

The `$1` backreference simply saves repetition by capturing the file basename from the requested URL. Otherwise, this is the same as simply `RewriteRule ^image\.jpg$ image.php [L]`.

There is nothing you need to do with regards to the query string, as this is copied to the target URL as-is by default.

Comment: would it be equivalent to use: RewriteRule ^image\.jpg$ image.php [L]

Comment: Yes, the very same. (I've updated my answer to just add that.)

Comment: do you need the QSA flag also?

Comment: No, the `QSA` flag is not required, since you are not "merging" URL parameters. As I stated, the original query string is copied onto the _susbtitution_ string by default. The `QSA` flag would only be required if you were adding additional URL parameters and you required the original query string to be appended. eg. Request `image.jpg?a=1&b=2&c=4` and you required `image.php?foo=123&bar=456&a=1&b=2&c=4`